css media query applied to onchainkit swap wont work
I am tryng to have my swap move down as the screen teh website is viewed on gets bigger. Everyhting looks good to me and my coding buddy but the media querys just dont work.I wrapped the swap in a div called "swap-components" and then tied the media queries to that div, I also imported the css file properly. I am not sure why the media query wont apply.
swapPosition.css
.swap-components {
    margin-top: 0; /* Default margin */
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { /* Medium devices and up */
    .swap-components {
        margin-top: 2.5rem; /* 40px */
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) { /* Large devices and up */
    .swap-components {
        margin-top: 5rem; /* 80px */
    }
}

SwapComponents.tsx
   import { 
  Swap, 
  SwapAmountInput, 
  SwapToggleButton, 
  SwapButton,
  SwapSettings,
  SwapSettingsSlippageInput,
  SwapSettingsSlippageTitle 
} from '@coinbase/onchainkit/swap'; 

import { useAccount } from 'wagmi';
import type { Token } from '@coinbase/onchainkit/token';
import Image from 'next/image';
import brettPic from './images/brettPic.png';
import ethL from './images/ethL.png';
import usdcLL from './images/usdcLL.png';
import sigL from './images/sigLL.png';
import './swapPosition.css';
import './swapStyles.css';
import './swapFont.css';
import './swapInp.css';


import { WalletComponents } from './WalletComponents';


export default function SwapComponents() {
  const { address } = useAccount();

  const ETHToken: Token = {
    address: "",
    chainId: 8453,
    decimals: 18,
    name: "Ethereum",
    symbol: "ETH",
    image: ethL.src,
  };

  const USDCToken: Token = {
    address: "0x833589fCD6eDb6E08f4c7C32D4f71b54bdA02913",
    chainId: 8453,
    decimals: 6,
    name: "USDC",
    symbol: "USDC",
    image: usdcLL.src,
  };


  const TESTToken: Token = {
    address: "0xA79B01ABB577BC0c1a01ee80Cb677ce34df5E889",
    chainId: 8453,
    decimals: 18,
    name: "Test",
    symbol: "ASND",
    image: sigL.src,
  };

  const swappableTokens: Token[] = [ETHToken, USDCToken,TESTToken];

  const isWalletConnected = !!address;

  return (
    <div className="swap-components"> 
    <Swap className='bg-white font-roboto-mono' title="">
      <SwapSettings className="swap-settings-component">

        <SwapSettingsSlippageTitle>
          Slippage
        </SwapSettingsSlippageTitle>
        <SwapSettingsSlippageInput />
      </SwapSettings>

      <SwapAmountInput
        label=""
        swappableTokens={swappableTokens}
        token={ETHToken}
        type="from"
        className='bg-white border-white swap-amount-input small-token-amount'
      />
      <SwapAmountInput
        label=""
        token={TESTToken}
        type="to"
        className='bg-white swap-amount-input small-token-amount'
      />

      {/* Disable the SwapButton if the wallet is not connected */}
      <SwapButton 
        className='bg-white border-white' 
        disabled={!isWalletConnected}
      />

      {!isWalletConnected && (
        <div className="mt-4 text-center text-red-500">
          Please connect your wallet to swap.
        </div>
      )}
    </Swap>
    </div>
  );
}

